# How to write an invocable class error method

Tags: invocable-method

Suppose you have an invocable method. How do you write an error message?.

```
   public class AccountQueryAction {
  @InvocableMethod(label='Get Account Names' description='Returns the list of account names corresponding to the specified account IDs.')
  public static List<String> getAccountNames(List<ID> ids) {
    List<String> accountNames = new List<String>();
    List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Id in :ids];
    for (Account account : accounts) {
      accountNames.add(account.Name);
    }
    return accountNames;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One mechanism would be to throw a custom exception with your desired error message.

```
public class AccountQueryAction {

    @InvocableMethod(label='Get Account Names' description='Returns the list of account names corresponding to the specified account IDs.')
    public static List<String> getAccountNames(List<ID> ids) {
        List<String> accountNames = new List<String>();
        List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Id in :ids];

        for (Account account : accounts) {
            accountNames.add(account.Name);
        }

        // if there were account names return them, otherwise error
        if (!accountNames.isEmpty()) {
            return accountNames;
        } else {
            throw new AccountQueryActionException('No accounts were returned');
        }
    }

    public class AccountQueryActionException extends Exception {}
}
```

Comment: Hi @Mark Pond. It doesn't show any error. Should there be any values inside the **public class AccountQueryActionException extends Exception {}**